# Filter results in GraphQL query

Tags: graphql

Given a headless WordPress backend, I have a GraphQL query making requests to the backend from my React app for all media given a search string. However, I need to return results of media that don't have a given `altText` value associated with them. I can retrieve the media and get the altText value, but not sure how to say "all media that don't have this value as the altText".

```
mediaItems(where: {search: $search}) {
nodes {
  title
  mediaType
  date
  mimeType
  guid
  altText <== How to specify value to filter so that it's "results that aren't X value"?
 }
}
```

So the `altText` would be like altText !== to 'given-string'

Comment: GraphQL has no built-in filtering (or sorting, or pagination or similar features). Whether you can filter by this field and how you do so are questions that are specific to the individual service you're querying. You can check the appropriate documentation or view the schema in the GraphiQL interface for your server, if it exposes one. This is not really a question that can be answered on here.

Comment: `altText` equals `null` ?

Comment: @xadm - are you saying to implement that in the GraphQL query or logic of the rendered results?

Comment: use graphiql and try to use this as condition ... I don't know if/how it is supported ... https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#search-parameters ?